# Assigning new value to a variable cleans old value from memory?

Tags: javascript

I have a class that holds a reference to another class

```
class Monkey {
  constructor(){
    this.banana = null 
  }

  getNewBanana() {
    this.banana = new Banana()
  }

  ...otherMethods

}
```

If I call `getNewBanana` more than one time, the instances of `Banana` will be deleted from memory? Or I need to do something to delete it?

I'm going to make a class that will do alot of `this.something = new AnyThing()` and I want to make sure that there is no memory leak or something like that.

Comment: This code alone won't leak. But obviously, other code that can hold a reference to that `Banana` might leak.

Comment: What would be `other code` ?

Comment: E.g. something else does `b = monkey.banana`. Now `b` holds a reference to that Banana.

Comment: @Vencovsky, `var monkey = new Monkey(); someArr.push(monkey.banana)`, for example...

Comment: anything that has a reference to it. i'd readup on garbage collection.

Comment: What is wrong to my question? Why someone wants to close it?

Comment: Is there a way to set all other references to null or "destroy" the object?

Comment: @Vencovsky Likely because reading up on garbage collection would have answered this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://javascript.info/garbage-collection, automatic Garbage Collector removes the unreachable object from memory, so there won't be a memory leak, however, the garbage collector tries to run only while the CPU is idle, to reduce the possible effect on the execution. If the Banana object is very huge and the application does lots of processes while creating many of the objects it can affect the app performance.